# Beautiful Soup - For loop not iterating through all tags within td

Tags: python, iframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape some data from a website using BeautifulSoup. I can select the td tag, but it does not contain all the child tags I would expect. My goal is to iterate through the td tag that has the id="highlight_today" and retrieve all of today's events. The url I'm attempting to scrape is http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-iframe-container. This is an iframe within another page, http://www.bloomberg.com/markets/economic-calendar. I think that another iframe may be the reason my for loop is not working and I'm not retrieving all the tags I would expect within this td. My html experience is very limited so I'm not sure. My code is as follows:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url_to_scrape = 'http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-iframe-container'
r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for events in soup.find('td', {'id': "highlight_today"}):
     print events.text
```

I am expecting to retrieve all the tags contained within the td, but it ends up stopping on this item in the html code and doesn't proceed to the next div in the td:

```
 <span class="econoarticles"><a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476382&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Daniel Tarullo Speaks<br></a></span>
```

There may be a better way to accomplish this than my current code. I'm still pretty amateurish at this, so open to any and all suggestions on how to accomplish my goal.

Answer (score 0):

`soup.find()` returns **one** tag.  Perhaps you meant to use `find_all()`?

Also, why are you expecting to find more than one element with a given ID?  HTML IDs are (supposed to be) unique across the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Use Selenium web driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import datetime
import csv
import re
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd #use pandas dataframe to store downloaded data
from StringIO import StringIO

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get("http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-iframe-container")
time.sleep(5)
table=driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]")
#table=driver.find_element_by_class_name('eventstable')
columns=table.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
time.sleep(1)
#option 1 get the hole column
for col in columns:
    print(col.text)
#option 2 get info row by row, but information is hided in to different classes
for col in columns_list:
    rows=col.find_elements_by_tag_name('div')
    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
    rows=col.find_elements_by_tag_name('span')
    for row in rows:
        print(row.text)
```

The result for the last news column will be:

```
Market Focus »


Daniel Tarullo Speaks
10:15 AM ET

Baker-Hughes Rig Count
1:00 PM ET

John Williams Speaks
2:30 PM ET
```

You can parse this strings. Use different class names to search necessary info.

Comment: Why would you need selenium?

Comment: The question's author asked for all suggestion to accomplish his goal. I usually use Selenium, because it allows more functionality (make a click on web elements in case of interactive web page and so on). Some times its better to use more general approach even for simple tasks if you know it well.

Comment: Selenium is painfully slow and really the last thing I ever try to use, there is no dynamic content so there is no use case for it here.

Comment: I thought it was interesting. I probably wouldn't use Selenium in this case either but that doesn't mean an answer like this should immediately be shot down.

Answer (score 0):

There is one *td* with the id highlight_today, all the children are contained in the tag so you just pull that and if you wanted to iterate over the children you would call find_all:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url_to_scrape = 'http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-iframe-container'
r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
event = soup.find('td', {'id': "highlight_today"})
for tag in event.find_all():
    print(tag)
```

Which would give you:

```
<div class="econoitems"><br/><span class="econoitems"><a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476407&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Market Focus <span class="econo-item-arrow">»</span></a></span><br/></div>
<br/>
<span class="econoitems"><a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476407&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Market Focus <span class="econo-item-arrow">»</span></a></span>
<a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476407&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Market Focus <span class="econo-item-arrow">»</span></a>
<span class="econo-item-arrow">»</span>
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="itembreak"></div>
<br/>
<span class="econoarticles"><a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476382&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Daniel Tarullo Speaks<br/></a></span>
<a href="byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476382&amp;cust=b-us&amp;year=2016&amp;lid=0&amp;containerId=eco-iframe-container&amp;prev=/byweek.asp#top">Daniel Tarullo Speaks<br/></a>
<br/>
```

The html is actually broken so you will need either *lxml* or *html5lib* to parse i. Then to get what you want, you need to find the spans with the `econoarticles` class and do a little bit of extra work to get the times:

```
 url_to_scrape = 'http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-iframe-container'
r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
html = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
event = soup.find('td', {'id': "highlight_today"})
for span in event.select("span.econoarticles"):
    speaker, time, a = span.text, span.find_next_sibling(text=True), span.a["href"]
    print(speaker, time, a)
```

Which if we run, give you:

```
In [2]: import requests
   ...: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   ...: url_to_scrape = 'http://b-us.econoday.com/byweek.asp?containerId=eco-ifr
   ...: ame-container'
   ...: r = requests.get(url_to_scrape)
   ...: html = r.content
   ...: soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
   ...: event = soup.find('td', {'id': "highlight_today"})
   ...: for span in event.select("span.econoarticles"):
   ...:     speaker, time, a = span.text, span.find_next_sibling(text=True), spa
   ...: n.a["href"]
   ...:     print(speaker, time, a)
   ...: 

Daniel Tarullo Speaks 10:15 AM ET byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476382&cust=b-us&year=2016&lid=0&containerId=eco-iframe-container&prev=/byweek.asp#top
John Williams Speaks 2:30 PM ET byshoweventfull.asp?fid=476390&cust=b-us&year=2016&lid=0&containerId=eco-iframe-container&prev=/byweek.asp#top

In [3]:
```

if you want the `Market Focus` and the url for that, just add:

```
event = soup.find('td', {'id': "highlight_today"})
det = event.select_one("span.econoitems")
name, an = det.text, det.a["href"]
print(name, an )
```

Comment: Thank you @PadraicCunningham this works perfectly for my purposes. After struggling to get lxml installed(finally figured it out). This works beautifully. Just needed one slight edit so I could get everything I was looking for: `for span in event.select("span.econoarticles, div.econoevents"):`